# How to close (only the window not the connection) of the VNC server platform who are open (but hide) in startup

Tags: vnc

How to close (or don't opened) at startup (only the window not the connection) of the VNC server platform who are open (but hide) in startup.

I tried this code in python ... it work, but it reopened. I want this window permanently closed (or not open at startup) with a code or what ever. (!NOT THE CONNECTION!, only the platform). This is my code who currently work for close but, VNC reopen it automatically after my close:

```
#****************************************************************************#
#                          -*- coding: utf-8  -*-                            #
#****************************************************************************#


import subprocess
import re

def get_window_id(window_name):
    xwininfo_output = subprocess.check_output(['xwininfo', '-root', '-tree']).decode('utf-8')
    match = re.search(r'(\w+) "(.*?' + window_name + '.*?")', xwininfo_output)
    
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        return None

def close_window_by_name(window_name):
    window_id = get_window_id(window_name)
    
    if window_id:
        subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'windowkill', window_id])
        print "Window {} Closed with sucess.".format(window_name)
    else:
        print "Window {} didn't found.".format(window_name)

close_window_by_name("VNC Server")

#**************************************************************#
```

I also tried (but totaly kill VNC, and this is not what I want):

kill [...], pkill [...], killall [...] for all process number "ps aux"

I also tried used :
xdotool selectwindow
and kill with the number. (It worked but...)
I searched the name with xdotool command with the number, and the window have no name.
Kill work with the number, but with no name I can't do it with this solution

finally I think the best way is disactivated the window platform (without disactivating the VNC network connection), but I don't know how